# The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

I am getting the error, when trying to deploy the mvc website :

> The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) does not have write access to 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'

I have tried the following solutions ,but still getting the samer error :

1. Re-installed IIS
2. Ran the following commands in cmd :

   ```
   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis -ga "NT Authority\Network Service"
   &
   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -i
   ```

Answer (score 0):

for very simple and basic solution try to give all necessary permission for this folder, and maybe for root folder also

Comment: I have already given all the permissions to all the users, still the problem persist.

Comment: sorry for stupid question, but when you add permissions - do you set full access?

Comment: Yes I have given full control